# How to attach contract code as attachment so that the contract can run during verify?

Tags: corda

```
Good examples of how attachments are meant to be used include:

Calendar data
Fixes (e.g. LIBOR)
Smart contract code
```

In what way can I leverage on attachment to parameterise values or even codify custom agreement rules so contract can validate using it? 
i.e

```
"Custom contract code must pass." using openAttachment(hashId).run == true
```

I want to be able to create a state that has a template of rules, but at the same time, able to handle custom (any) new rules proposed by initiator, and accepted by counterparties.

Answer (score 0):

Contract code is attached automatically. These are the contracts that are assigned to a state when adding state as an output within a transaction.

These would be the standard "template of rules" that everyone has pre-agreed to in the development of the CorDapp and are run by everyone to reach consensus.

In theory, you could add a custom contract in an attachment, have counterparties upload the contract class to their nodes and then run verify against them by calling verify explicitly against the class within the flow. I suspect you'd have to have counterparty nodes stop and restart to load the class dynamically onto the classpath though.